# Can a warlock make a pact with a god?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, warlock, religions-and-deities

Are there rules for a warlock making a pact with a chaotic, evil, or chaotic evil god?

Comment: Do you mean to have such a pact be made in the character's background as the origin of the warlock's powers? Or do you want know if the warlock can make such a pact to increase his powers after the game's begun? (*Please* don't say both—pick one then, if interested, and ask a separate question about the other! `:-)`)

Answer (score 6):

**There are no rules for pacts**

In 3.5, there are no rules whatsoever for Warlocks making pacts. There is some fluff about either warlocks or their ancestors having maybe had some dealings with evil outsiders at some point, but pacts are simply not mechanically part of the 3.5 warlock class.

If you want to make a pact with a dark god as part of your backstory, talk to your DM and go for it. That sounds like a great character hook! It has no mechanical implications without house rules though.

Answer (score 6):

The description in *Complete Arcane* is pretty vague as to what, exactly, happens to a warlock to give him his powers. Much of the text is intentionally left very broad, to allow for a variety of warlocks.

Then a few statements suggest that warlocks only derive from pacts with fiends, which is rather frustrating.

Anyway, I recommend following the majority of the text, and ignoring the few statements that suggest otherwise. To be consistent with this bulk of the text, I also recommend ignoring the warlock’s alignment restriction, but this isn’t necessary.

When you do this (regardless of any changes to the alignment requirements), then it becomes clear that it is quite possible for a warlock to receive their powers from a pact with a Chaotic and/or Evil god.

Note that this is different from what clerics and other divine spellcasters do. Divine spellcasters pray to their gods for power, and their gods answer those prayers. A warlock does not do this. A warlock has made a one time bargain with a power sufficient to change him or her and grant him access to invocations. Once made, this bargain is typically considered irrevocable; there is no such thing as a fallen (redeemed?) warlock, no such thing as an ex-warlock. Even if the warlock takes up arms against its former sponsor, the books give no indication that the patron could remove those powers at that point.

But all of this is backstory. There are no rules for this. There aren’t even detailed descriptions. It’s all left very purposefully vague to allow you to make up what you want here.

Comment: KRyan has made good points. There are prestige classes that allow for warlocks to derive their power from fey as well as fiends. Fey are almost always chaotic. Warlocks' pacts, as KRyan has pointed out, a technically fluff, unless it is explicitly mentioned in a prestige class, such as Hellfire Warlock (Mephistopheles - a Devil Lord). So if chaotic fey are allowed, and lawful fiends are allowed, there should be no problem in allowing deities as well.